# Weblogic OBIEE 11g failed to start as Windows Service

Tags: java, windows, service, weblogic-10.x, obiee

Below error is being thrown while trying to start as service:

```
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszCmdLine = -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseSpinning  -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true   -da -Dplatform.home=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Dcommon.components.home=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1 -Djrockit.optfile=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\NAOR-DEVOBIAP01 -Doracle.domain.config.dir=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\config\FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\servers\NAOR-DEVOBIAP01\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -DEPM_ORACLE_HOME=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1 -DHYPERION_HOME=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1 -DEPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE=novalue -Dhyperion.home=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1 -DEPM_REG_PROPERTIES_PATH=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\USER_P~1\domains\BIFOUN~1\config\fmwconfig -Depm.useApplicationContextId=false -Doracle.biee.search.bisearchproperties=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\jee\BISearchConfig.properties -Dweblogic.management.clearTextCredentialAccessEnabled=true -Doracle.notification.filewatching.interval=2000 -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enableJSSE=true -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Dbi.oracle.home=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1 -DEPM_ORACLE_HOME=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1 -Doracle.ecsf.security.service=oracle.biee.search.security.BISearchSecurityService -Doracle.ecsf.configuration.class=oracle.biee.search.services.BISearchServiceConfiguration -Dxdo.server.config.dir=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain\config\bipublisher -DXDO_FONT_DIR=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\common\fonts  -Drtd.instanceName=RTD_NAOR-DEVOBIAP01 -Dem.oracle.home=E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\oracle_common -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath -classpath     E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\wlserver_10.3\server\lib;E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\wlserver_10.3\server\bin\classpath.txt -Dweblogic.Name=NAOR-DEVOBIAP01 -Dweblogic.management.username=  -Dweblogic.class.path="e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib" -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Djava.security.policy="e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy" weblogic.Server
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszJavaHome = E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~2\jdk
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszExecDir E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszOldPath = E:\appx32\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\bin;E:\Informatica\9.0.1\server\bin;e:\Informatica\9.0.1\tools\datadirect;e:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\tools\datadirect;e:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;E:\Oracle_Client_Home\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Oracle_Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\products\Essbase\EssbaseServer\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\opmn\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\opmn\lib;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\perl\bin;
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszNewPath = e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64\;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~2\jdk\jre\bin;E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\ORACLE~2\jdk\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8;E:\appx32\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\bin;E:\Informatica\9.0.1\server\bin;e:\Informatica\9.0.1\tools\datadirect;e:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\tools\datadirect;e:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;E:\Oracle_Client_Home\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;E:\Oracle_Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\products\Essbase\EssbaseServer\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\opmn\bin;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\opmn\lib;e:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\Oracle_BI1\perl\bin;
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszDelay = 0
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszStopClass = []
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszLog = [E:\OBIEE11g\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain\servers\AdminServer\AdminServer-stdout.txt]
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] Thread created successfully
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] Reporting SCM of SERVICE_START_PENDING with delay=0
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszHost = []
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszPort = []
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [StartJVM] Parsing JVM Arguments
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [StartJVM] Initializing JVM
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] Reporting SCM of SERVICE_RUNNING
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [ServiceStart] waiting for multiple events
[Thu Aug 15 08:37:31 2013] [I] [RunJavaApp] Loading class - weblogic.Server
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.Server
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Person who setup the class path redirecting the output to a text file, some where he read from the blog and using that file as a class path back..but for some reason Weblogic is not able to load the jars as in classpath.

```
 -Dweblogic.class.path="<WEBLOGIC_HOME>/server/bin/classpath.txt"
```

Changed the configuration to use %CLASSPATH% in InstallSvc.cmd file definition and tested it. It works.

```
--classpath %CLASSPATH%
```